# AVL tree - required: String, found: AVL

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

```
static String min ( AVLStringTreeNode t ) {
    if( t == null )
        return t;
    while( t.left != null ) // location of error
        t = t.left;
    return t.val;
}
```

Constructor for AVLStringTreeNode:

```
public class AVLStringTreeNode
{
    public String val;
    public int height;
    public AVLStringTreeNode left, right;
}
```

Error:

```
incompatible types required: java.lang.String found: AVLStringTreeNode
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it runtime error?

Comment: It is a compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is String, yet when t is null, you return t, which is AVLStringTreeNode.

Try this:

```
static String min ( AVLStringTreeNode t ) {
    if( t == null )
        return null;
    while( t.left != null ) // location of error
        t = t.left;
    return t.val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to re-write your while code like this -

```
while( t.left != null ){
   if(t.left!=null){     
      t = t.left; 
  }
}
```

The error might occurred because once `t.left` become null. So it check against null.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.